# Recover electrum wallet with only wallet file?

Tags: electrum, wallet-recovery

I have an electrum wallet file and I thought I created a backup of the seed, but now I cannot find it anywhere.

When I try use it with the current version of electrum, it won't open it.

Is there anyway to recover the coins from the wallet file?